# Scroll UITableview with changing height and text fields to avoid keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to set up tableview to scroll when a text field that would be hidden behind a keyboard is selected. I've tried multiple methods that I've found around including using keyboard notifications, textFieldDid/ShouldBegin/EndEditing etc, but none of them seem to work every time.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working with:

[image: Screenshot]

I have two issues:

First, I'm using a date picker in place of a keyboard for my bottom text field (off screen in the screenshot but you can get the idea). Since this isn't technically the keyboard, the methods I've used for setting the keyboard offset aren't working for this text field. I'm sure I can get the height of the date picker and adjust accordingly if that is the currently selected item, but I was wondering if there was an easier way of incorporating this into the keyboard methods.

Second, when more cells are added, the offsets become incorrect. The way this view is set up is a table view divided into sections. When the user taps the "Add further support" button, it inserts a row into the support section. It seems like the height change that happens because of this is not being registered when I try to set the table scroll offset. Is there a way I can get the height to register properly?

Here's some relevant code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = textField;
    [self setOffsetForKeyboard];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.activeField == self.dateTextField) {
        [self datePickerValueChanged:nil];
    }
    self.activeField = nil;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    self.keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    [self setOffsetForKeyboard];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self.myTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, -(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + kStatusBarHeight))animated:YES];
}

- (void)setOffsetForKeyboard{
    CGPoint location =[self.activeField.superview convertPoint:self.activeField.frame.origin toView:nil];
    if (location.y > self.view.frame.size.height - self.keyboardSize.height-kKeyboardOffset) {
        [self.myTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, location.y-self.keyboardSize.height-kKeyboardOffset) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution , you will love it->

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: This looks pretty good, but it had some weird behavior. I ended up just subclassing uitableviewcontroller instead

Comment: @Ian Agree. People keep throwing that library around these questions but it's really buggy.

Comment: @MattQuiros- add your own code in TPKeyboardAvoiding class... i have added my own codes in it, and its running perfectly. So my friend, you must know how to improvise 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just subclassing UITableViewController which has this functionality built in instead of UIViewController which is what I was using before. Works like a charm!